# What is this "device" from Hunt Manufacturing Co. in Statesville NC used for?

Tags: clamps

What is this "device" from Hunt Manufacturing Co. in Statesville NC used for? It is made of aluminum with a swivel part (for attaching to table, maybe)?[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a hinge clamp meant to hold a silkscreen frame for printing. You'd screw the part with the two holes to a work surface, and you'd probably do the same with another clamp just like this one. Then you could insert a frame over which a silkscreen is stretched into the clamp part and tighten it down. That lets you flip the screen up and down so that you could make multiple prints in the same place with one screen. You'd likely also set up some guides to hold the paper (or whatever you're printing on) in place. And you might have several of these setups, one for each of several colors, so that the different colors register appropriately.

From what I can tell, Hunt Manufacturing became the Speedball Corporation, which still sells clamps exactly like this one. Here's a [listing on Blick.com](https://www.dickblick.com/products/speedball-deluxe-hinge-clamps/).

[image: hinge clamp]

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it.